# Getting ElasticSearch document fields inside of loaded records in searchkick

Tags: searchkick

Is it possible to get ElasticSearch document fields inside of loaded AR records?

Here is a gist that illustrates what I mean: https://gist.github.com/allomov/39c30905e94c646fb11637b45f43445d

In this case I want to avoid additional computation of `total_price` after getting response from ES. The solution that I currently see is to include the relationship and run `total_price` computation for each record, which is not so optimal way to perform this operation, as I see it.

```rb
result = Product.search("test", includes: :product_components).response
products_with_total_prices = result.map do |product|
  {
    product: product
    total_price: product.product_components.map(&:price).compact.sum
  }
end
```

Could you please tell if it is possible to mix ES document fields into AR loaded record?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware it isn't possible to get a response that merges the document fields into the loaded record.

Usually I prefer to completely rely on the data in the indexed document where possible (using `load: false` as a search option), and only load the AR record(s) as a second step if necessary. For example:

```rb
result = Product.search("test", load: false).response

# If you also need AR records, could do something like:
product_ids    = result.map(&:id)
products_by_id = {}

Product.where(id: product_ids).find_each do |ar_product|
  products_by_id[ar_product.id] = ar_product
end

merged_result = result.map do |es_product|
  es_product[:ar_product] = products_by_id[es_product.id]}
end
```

Additionally, it may be helpful to retrieve the document stored in the ES index for a specific record, which I would normally do by defining the following method in your Product class:

```rb
def es_document
  return nil unless doc = Product.search_index.retrieve(self).presence
  Hashie::Mash.new doc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select: true` and the `with_hit` method to get the record and the search document together. For your example:

```rb
result = Product.search("test", select: true)
products_with_total_prices =
  result.with_hit.map do |product, hit|
    {
      product: product,
      total_price: hit["_source"]["total_price"]
    }
  end
```